# In need of accurate translations for "discount"

Tags: terminology, translation, french, finance, money

I’m writing a program for [point of sales](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_of_sale) work. Thus, in my code, I need to
name things (in English) related to concerns like "Store", "Sales",
"Price", etc.

I’m now writing code related to "Discount" concepts. The thing I’m
currently struggling on is that I have three similar but different
concepts with three different names in French, with loose English translations provided for each:

1. [*rabais*](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/rabais/65821?q=rabais#65074) – Diminution du prix d’un bien ou d’un service sur un prix préalablement proposé ou facturé. 
    [~ *Reduction in the previously provided or invoiced price of a good or service.* ~]
2. [*remise*](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/remise/68010?q=remise#67257) – Diminution de prix accordée sur un achat par un commerçant : *Une remise de 5 %.* 
    [~ *Price cut granted by a merchant for a purchase:* a discount of 5%. ~].
3. [*escompte*](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/escompte/30986?q=escompte#30899) – Réduction consentie par un commerçant à l’acheteur qui paie comptant ou au débiteur qui s’acquitte de sa dette avant l’échéance. 
    [~ *(Price) reduction granted by a merchant to the buyer who pays cash or to the debtor who pays off his debt early*. ~]

Not being a native English speaker, I can’t find an accurate translation
for each of these words. I only found *discount* or *rebate* but I don’t
really know to which of these concept it best applies.

Does someone know more accurate English translations for each of these
distinct but related terms?

---

If it helps, [this site](https://go.sellsy.com/fr/blog/facturation/remise-rabais-reductions-escompte-ristourne-quelles-sont-les-differences/) (in French) contains a very precise
description of the differences between these concepts. Here
are excerpts:

> ## L’escompte
>
> L’escompte est une réduction financière accordée en cas de règlement
> comptant. En d’autres termes, c’est la somme déduite à un débiteur
> qui acquitte sa dette avant l’échéance. [...]

> ## Le rabis
>
> En comptabilité, le rabais est une réduction commerciale
> exceptionnelle du prix de vente accordée au client pour un défaut de
> qualité des produits de conformité de la commande aux caractéristiques
> prédéfinies ou d’un retard de livraison. [...]

> ## La remise
>
> Une remise est une réduction commerciale habituelle accordée en fonction
> des quantités achetées, dans le cadre d’une opération promotionnelle
> ou suivant la qualité du client. Généralement, ces remises sont
> accordées aux clients qui achètent des quantités importantes [...]

> ## La ristourne
>
> La ristourne est une réduction de prix accordée sur le montant global
> des ventes faites avec un même tiers-client ou fournisseur pendant
> une période déterminée (mois, trimestre, semestre, etc.). Elle se
> calcule alors sur le chiffre d’affaires réalisé avec le client durant
> la période retenue, en général la fin de l’année. [...]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it involves a detailed knowledge of French as well as English. Linguistics.SE might help, but possibly a dedicated business linguistics site is required.

Comment: Check definitions of discount and rebate to see which is closest. Some businesses also advertise "cash back", which may be relevant.

Comment: You can improve this question by giving a brief description, in English, of the difference in concept between these three French words.  It's possible that business English does not make the same distinctions that business French does,  but maybe it does.

Comment: Here are some synonyms for "discount".  https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/discount

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I’ve given the Larousse definitions for each of the three French finance terms, along with off-the-cough translations into English. This should suffice to make the question suitable for a site in English.

Comment: @tchrist Still three separate questions, all of which would doubtless attract the early answer 'discount'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The problem with making it three separate questions each drawing the selfsame *discount* as their answers is that if you did that, you would completely lose track that French makes a nuanced distinction for each of the three scenarios. That said, I am by no means convinced that English **actually *has*** three distinct terms you could use here which would be commonly recognized by the general populace rather than by finance geeks alone.

Comment: That's assuming that the French jargon and the English jargon hereabouts have correspondences wrt referents.  Though 'escompte' looks very much like 'cash discount'.